# Serve WordPress in root path of Apache

Tags: buddypress, apache

I am new to WordPress, I want that when I go to `localhost` I get my WordPress site, and I don't have to go to `localhost/wordpress`. This is because I am working with BuddyPress which does not work with `installations where you give WordPress its own directory.`

I am trying:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress

# /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', '/');

# /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-load.php
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', '/');
```

When I tried the first two files only, it worked partially: `localhost` rendered WordPress site but without style.

What is the usual approach to set this up? Am I doing the right thing: to move WordPress to root? or does BuddyPress is referring to other thing?

## Update

```
apachectl -M | grep -i write
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
 rewrite_module (shared)
```

Links are pointing to `http://localhost/wordpress/activity/` should I make them to point to `http://localhost/activity/`? how?

Comment: why do you not just move everything into `html`, rather than leave it in `wordpress` directory?

Comment: thanks, I did it but I am getting 404 when clicking in any buddypress link, I have mod_rewrite enabled, check my update

Comment: you did what? moved the files to root? if URLs are wrong, your site and home option values are incorrect.

Comment: yes, everything was messed up, check my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After copying WordPress files in the DocumentRoot of Apache server. I found that URLs where rendered as `wordpress/qwe`.

So I removed all the files in DocumentRoot and installed WordPress again. By copying the **contents**, NOT the directory, of the downloaded WordPress to the DocumentRoot of Apache server.

Installation makes the URLs to be in the root: `localhost/index.php` and and the links in the pages also `localhost/qwe`, i.e. without `wordpress`.

I did not change anything in configuration files, everything I did was from the browser.